# Swift/Cocoa: How do I export an AVMutableComposition as wav or aiff audio file

Tags: swift, avfoundation, core-audio, avassetwriter

I have a `AVMutableComposition` containing only audio that I want to export to a .wav audio file.

The simplest solution for exporting audio I found was using `AVAssetExportSession` like in this simplified example:

```
let composition = AVMutableComposition()
// add tracks...

let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition,
                                         presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)!
exportSession.outputFileType = .m4a
exportSession.outputURL = someOutUrl
exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
    // done
}
```

But it only works for .m4a

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10635672/921573) mentions that in order to export to other formats, one would have to use `AVAssetReader` and `AVAssetWriter`, unfortunately though it does not go into further details.

I have tried to implement it but got stuck in the process.
This is what I have so far (again simplified):

```
let composition = AVMutableComposition()
let outputSettings: [String : Any] = [
    AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
    AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false,
    AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
    AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 32,
    AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: false,
    AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
    AVChannelLayoutKey: NSData(),
]

let assetWriter = try! AVAssetWriter(outputURL: someOutUrl, fileType: .wav)
let input = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio, outputSettings: outputSettings)
assetWriter.add(input)
assetWriter.startWriting()
assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: CMTime.zero)
input.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: .main) {

    // as I understand, I need to bring in data from my
    // AVMutableComposition here...

    let sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer = ???
    input.append(sampleBuffer)
}

assetWriter.finishWriting {
    // done
}
```

It boils down to my question:

**Can you provide a working example for exporting audio from a AVMutableComposition to a wav file?**

Answer (score 1):

After some more research I came up with the following solution.
The missing piece was the usage of AVAssetReader.

(simplified code)

```
// composition
let composition = AVMutableComposition()
// add stuff to composition

// reader
guard let assetReader = try? AVAssetReader(asset: composition) else { return }
assetReader.timeRange = CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: CMTime(value: composition.duration.value, timescale: composition.duration.timescale))
let assetReaderAudioMixOutput = AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput(audioTracks: composition.tracks(withMediaType: .audio), audioSettings: nil)
assetReader.add(assetReaderAudioMixOutput)
guard assetReader.startReading() else { return }

// writer
let outputSettings: [String : Any] = [
    AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
    AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false,
    AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: false,
    AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 32,
    AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: false,
    AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0,
    AVChannelLayoutKey: NSData(),
]
guard let assetWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(outputURL: someOutUrl, fileType: .wav) else { return }
let writerInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio, outputSettings: outputSettings)
assetWriter.add(writerInput)
guard assetWriter.startWriting() else { return }
assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: CMTime.zero)

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "my.queue.id")
writerInput.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: queue) {

    // capture assetReader in my block to prevent it being released
    let readerOutput = assetReader.outputs.first!

    while writerInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
        if let nextSampleBuffer = readerOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() {
            writerInput.append(nextSampleBuffer)
        } else {
            writerInput.markAsFinished()
            assetWriter.endSession(atSourceTime: composition.duration)
            assetWriter.finishWriting() {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    // done, call my completion
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

as you mention you are creating .m4a successfully why not convert .m4a file to .wav file in just put some line of code

I simply changed the extension of the file to .wav and removed the .m4a file and it worked.

```
func getDirectory() -> URL {
    let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentDirectory = path[0]
    return documentDirectory
}

let date = Date().timeIntervalSince1970

fileName = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(date).m4a")
wavFileName = getDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(date).wav")

try! FileManager.default.copyItem(at: fileName, to: wavFileName)
try! FileManager.default.removeItem(at: fileName)
```

I even played .wav file and it's working fine.

```
audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: wavFileName)
audioPlayer.play()
```

check out above example is this extension replacement causing of any load or time in your app or not

Comment: So you are suggesting to just rename the file? It would still be a .m4a just with a different name.

Comment: no buddy it will not be .m4a file we are changing its extension not name

Comment: if you found this answer useful you can mark it as correct